# Error while installing tripleo Client Library

Tags: openstack, tripleo

When i try to download tripleo Client using command

```
yum install -y python-tripleoclient ceph-ansible
```

On Centos 7.5 , I am getting error curl#60 - "Peer's Certificate has expired."

[image: Peer's Certificate has expired Issue]

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with tripleo client itself. You are using some temporary yum repositories which were recycled.

My favorite hacking approach is to use [pip](https://pypi.org/project/python-tripleoclient/#description) to install it:

```
pip install python-tripleoclient
```

This is also documented on https://docs.openstack.org/python-tripleoclient/latest/installation.html